# Goal: 1 Webform as Block, Multiple Nodes with block in Panel pane

Tags: 7, webforms

I am trying to create a single webform that I can expose as a block and re-use on multiple 'profile' nodes.  These nodes will use Panels and Panel/Panes to display content.

Problem: I need to pass email address(s) stored on the "parent"('profile') node (cck fields perhaps) to the "child" webform so that the form is sent to the address(s).

I've tried following a few articles that said to create a custom module to implement hook_form_alter.  I haven't been able to get it to work.  I'm a bit of a noob at the whole programming side of Drupal so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view for this web form node, and display it as block.
This will work.

Answer (score 0):

In D7, you could go to "/node/%nid/webform/configure". Here under the "Advanced Settings" Tab, you could check the box "Available as block ". Your web-form will be available as a block now.

To pass the email address to the webform block, you could try using the [Webform Token](http://drupal.org/project/webform_tokens) along with the [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) Module.